# Как в порядке исключить числа кратные 3?

Tags: python, for, while

> Ввести с клавиатуры целое число n.
> Получить сумму кубов всех целых чисел от 1 до n(включая n).
> Исключения составляют все числа кратные цифре 3.
> Реализовать в 2-х вариантах: используя цикл while и цикл for

```
value = 1
num = int(input("Число: "))
for item in range(value, num +1):
   print(item)
result = sum(item ** 3 for item in range(value, num + 1))
print(result)
```

Как в этом порядке исключить числа кратные 3?

Comment: проверять остаток от деления на 3. Если он равен 0, то исключать.

Comment: остаток , я уже понял что нужно сделать, не совсем разобрался как исключить именно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вариант с `for`:

```
res = sum(v**3 for v in range(1, n + 1) if v % 3)
```

вариант c `while`:

```
res = 0
v = 1

while v <= n:
    if v % 3:
        res += v**3
```

вариант без `while` и `for`:

```
res = sum(map(lambda e: e**3, filter(lambda v: v % 3, range(1, n + 1))))
```

Comment: while v <= n:  - вечный цикл

Answer (score 1):

Вариант:

```
value = 1
result = 0
num = int(input("Число: "))

for item in range(value, num+1):
    if item % 3 != 0:
        result += item ** 3

print(f'Res: {result}')

result = 0
while num > 0:
    if num % 3 != 0:
        result += num ** 3
    num -= 1

print(f'Res: {result}')
```

Число: 6

Res: 198

Res: 198

Comment: `value` - это константа. Для констант принято использовать прописные буквы: `VALUE`.

Comment: value используется один раз, так что и не нужна совсем

Comment: так в исходнике было

Comment: можно использовать автоматичесое приведение чисел к логическим значениям: `while num:` `if num % 3:`